# How to know if the triggered events succeed or fail in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-events

I trigger an event in Yii2 transaction, and I want to know if the event handler succeed to commit the transaction, or fail to rollback.

Is a global variable or class const the right way?

What I do now is throwing an error in the event handlers.

Comment: ummm... if your transaction is used within the `try{}catch(){}` block if there is an exception in the event it would be caught automatically isnt it? or you are talking about the correct execution of the event logic?

Comment: Yes, I tend to mean the correct logic execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you're using event object to store state of event. Create custom event:

```
class MyEvent extends Event {

    public $isCommited = false;
}
```

Use it on trigger and check the result:

```
$event = new MyEvent();
$this->trigger('myEvent', $event);
if ($event->isCommited) {
    // do something
}
```

In event handler you need to set this property:

```
function ($event) {
    // do something
    $event->isCommited = true;
}
```

---

If you want to break event flow you may use [`$handled`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-event#$handled-detail) property instead of `isCommited` and custom event.

Comment: `isCommitted` is more flexible, event handler E1 set it to false to rollback the event sender's transaction, but the event handler E2 can also exec the sqls inside E2 wrapped within a nested transaction.